# How do get photos of the chosen album in Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, photos

This shows the names of the albums as links. When a specific link is chosen the user is being redirected to the albumPhotos.php file. What i need is to put the required code in albumPhotos.php so that the photos of the specific album appear.

```
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
Foreach($albums['data'] as $album) 
{
print ('<a href= "albumPhotos.php">'.$album['name'].'</a>'.'</br>' ) ;
}
```

This is the current code in the apbumPhotos.php. At the time it presents all of the photos of the user.

```
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
foreach($albums['data'] as $album)
  {

    $photos = $facebook->api("/{$album['id']}/photos");
    foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
    {
            echo "<img src='{$photo['source']}' />", "<br />";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass *which single album you want* to the `apbumPhotos.php` page. Otherwise, your code doesn't know which album link the user clicked on, and it's just looping through all of the user's albums. The logic is pretty simple.

Use a query string to pass the `album_id` as $_GET parameter in the link, like so:

```
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
foreach($albums['data'] as $album)  {
  print ('<a href="albumPhotos.php?album_id='.$album['id'].'">'.$album['name'].'</a>'.'</br>' ) ;
}
```

Then, get the `album_id` parameter in apbumPhotos.php and use it (instead of looping through ALL the albums again, which it is doing now):

```
$album_id = $_GET['album_id']; // get the album_id passed in the URL
$photos = $facebook->api("/{$album_id}/photos"); // just get that one album
foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
{
        echo "<img src='{$photo['source']}' />", "<br />";
}
```

Comment: it's worth noting, that you must handle paging, because it won't give you all photos of this album